# F# Generic constraint not working due to "ambiguity"

Tags: generics, f#, operator-overloading, constraints

I have an application, which renders piano sheets and I therefore have to abstract some musical notation concepts into record structures. To save some typing, I sometimes add the member `FromTuple` to some record types.

I also introduced the operator `!>`, which accepts a tuple and returns the appropriate tuple.
I do however have the following issue:

> FS0332:   Could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator 'FromTuple' at or near this program point. Consider using type annotations to resolve the ambiguity.

I cannot locate the actual source of my error (I first thought that some record field names might be defined/used in multiple record types, but that does not seem to be the case).

---

The type definitions:

```
type xyz =
    {
        // some record fields
        Field1 : int
        Field2 : bool
        Field3 : string * string
    }
    with
        static member FromTuple (a, b, c) = { Field1 = a; Field2 = b; Field3 = c }

// more types defined like `xyz`

[<AutoOpen>]
module Globals =
    let inline (!>) x = (^b : (static member FromTuple : ^a -> ^b) x)
```

The faulty line (in a separate file):

```
//ERROR
let my_xyz : xyz = !> (315, false, ("foo", "bar"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `xyz.FromTuple` method takes three separate parameters: `a: int`, `b: bool`, and `c: string * string`; instead, you need it to take a single `int * bool * (string * string)`. Do this by wrapping the parameters in another set of parenthesis:

```
static member FromTuple ((a, b, c)) = { Field1 = a; Field2 = b; Field3 = c }
```